# Asp.net concurrent calls issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, concurrency

I have a asp.net web application hosted on iis which returns reports. i have a sql stored proc which is called on display results(below is the code). when two users hits at the same exact time the counts are all messed up. Am clear the data set. i tried to set session state to the page directive as false and read only but it still not works

```
SqlCommand cmdcount = new SqlCommand("sp_GetCount", con);
cmdcount.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommandTimeOut"]);
cmdcount.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmdcount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", DpAc.SelectedItem.Value);
cmdcount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No", Dpfno.SelectedItem.Value);
cmdcount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", caltextbox.Text);
DataTable dt_ps = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

con.Open();
da.SelectCommand = cmdcount;
da.Fill(dt_ps);
Count.DataSource = dt_ps;
Count.DataBind();
d_ps.Clear();
Count.Visible = true;
con.Close();
```

Added below to the .aspx page

```
<% Page EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"%> and

<% Page EnableSessionState="False"%>
```

Output user 1

Count 35

output user 2

Count 45

Expected: both output should be 30 for both the users

Comment: 1. Are you sure you're passing in the right values to the stored proc? 2. What is the proc actually doing? 3. [Don't prefix your store proc names with `sp_`](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). 4. [Don't use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Yes, am passing the right values. The sproc returns counts. It works fine when its only one user hitting at a time. The issue occurs only when concurrent users hits at the same time. I will make note of other suggestions and change it :)

Comment: So is it the sproc returning the wrong numbers? If so, why aren't you showing us that code?

Comment: *when two users hits at the same exact time*: that is not possible because IIS will put both requests into a queue so one will be after or before the other. Your issue is something else.

Comment: What is `DpAc` and `Dpfno`? Are you sharing something like do you have a singleton or a static class in the code?

Comment: Dpac and Dpfno are selected values from the drop down. But the same sproc works when single user hits. Why is it breaking only with concurrent users. And when i add break point i see two requests coming in immediately meaning when i click F10 it goes to the first line again and come down

Comment: any suggestions please.. i have tried transaction scope too